# drupal service module

Tags: web-services, drupal

I am using services module drupal 6 in that comment services there. it contain count all method for count number of comments for particular node.then how to pass URL for that method.

Comment: do you mean endpoints? or callback URL? elaborate your question..

Comment: i am get comment-list with URL endpoint/comment. but i want a count all URL for node-id.

Answer (score 3):

use this URL in post method

endpoint/your_module_name/name_of_method/

and pass the parameter in poster
nid = your_node_id

and click on post method

Answer (score 1):

use this URL in post method

endpoint/comment/countAll/

pass parameter nid= 0.

Answer (score 1):

use poster this is add ons of firefox and in the poster use url

endpoint/your_module_name/name_of_method/

and pass the parameter in poster nid = your_node_id like (22)

and click on post method